# CSS A Hover Exclude Current Item

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to work with this Wordpress template I paid for, but the developers aren't of much help and I'm stuck...

The main navigation has a hover feature to pink, but I want the 'current-menu-item' to be excluded from going pink on hover. Proving very difficult to find the right class to edit.

I can see the below HTML and CSS styles...

[Home](http://www.royalteeapparel.co.uk/wp/)

The site is at the below location:

http://www.royalteeapparel.co.uk/wp

Thanks

Comment: style.css Line 452 ".menu-item a:hover"

Answer (score 1):

Add this:

```
.menu-item a:hover {color: #FF17A6 !important;}
/* add this */
.current-menu-item a:hover {color: #4AB1D3 !important;}
```

I would also suggest that you try to not use `!important` at all and work *with* CSS rather than against it, but it seems like the stylesheet already made heavy use of it.

Comment: Legends! Thank you ever so much!

Answer (score 0):

In your .css file
http://www.royalteeapparel.co.uk/wp/wp-content/themes/WhiteNoise/style.css  line 452,

change

```
.menu-item a:hover {
    color: #FF17A6 !important;
}
```

to what ever color suits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can also include this line.

```
.sf-menu li.current-menu-item a:hover
{
    color: #4AB1D3;
}
```

The CSS file already contains:

```
.sf-menu li.current-menu-item a
{
    color: #4AB1D3;
}
```

So adding the additional line to it to include the :hover on the a tag will get rid of the pink and make it the same blue as the selected item.